# How to display rows of data with the same date through bootstrap collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I'm trying to display data that are grouped by date. The view displays dates and should i click on it, all rows with the same date should be displayed. I'm quite lost on how to implement this feature.

Projects table

> id | name | user_id | date_submitted

Controller

```
public function projectsList()
{
  $projects = DB::table('projects')
    ->select('id', 'name', 'user_id', 'date_submitted')
    ->groupBy('date_submitted')
    ->get();
  return view('teacher.projectsList', compact('projects'));
}
```

View

```
<div class="accordion" id="datesubmitted">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
   <h2 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
      target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        //This is where rows of the same data appear
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I can display rows of data normally without it, but i'm stuck on how to integrate collapse/accordion to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove `->groupBy('date_submitted')` replace it with `->orderBy('date_submitted')`

> groupBy wont give you all data that u needs to display

then for displaying,
 simple keep a temp php   variable with the date if date changes create a new collapse hope it helps